# setTimeout and setInterval not executing in webview

Tags: android, webview, wkwebview

I am currently using setInterval to execute a function every X number of milliseconds in a webview on android. On newer android devices, the code runs, but in older devices, the timer never runs.

```
var timer = setInterval(function() {
  // call function
}, 500);
```

I had seen at another place that someone mentioned that using SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permissions can cause this problem, so I made sure to pull those settings to verify, but that didn't make a difference.

Any ideas on what setting may cause this to not work?